# Writing C#'s analog of setTimeout, setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: c#, timer

I got tired of starting timer every time I need to do something simple as running some function 5 seconds after something in my code happens. So I tried to write a function (actually, 3 of them: `setTimeout`, `setInterval` and `clearInterval`) to write one line of code when I need it instead of, say, five.

It is working, at least for the cases I tested.

I understand that maybe something in that code is not right, maybe I forgot about something. Should I improve anything in my approach?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace timeouts_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer[] timerList = new Timer[100];
        private int timerMaxIndex = -1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int aInterval = SetInterval(500, a);
            int bInterval = SetInterval(500, b);
            int cInterval = SetInterval(500, c);

            SetTimeout(3500, () =>
            {
                ClearInterval(aInterval);
            });

            SetTimeout(7000, () =>
            {
                ClearInterval(bInterval);
            });

            SetTimeout(10500, () =>
            {
                ClearInterval(cInterval);
            });
        }

        public void a()
        {
            label1.Text += "a";
        }

        public void b()
        {
            label1.Text += "b";
        }

        public void c()
        {
            label1.Text += "c";
        }

        public int SetInterval(int time, Action function)
        {
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            tmr.Interval = time;
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate (object s, EventArgs ev)
            {
                function();
            });
            tmr.Start();

            timerMaxIndex++;
            var index = timerMaxIndex;
            timerList[timerMaxIndex] = tmr;            
            return index;
        }

        public int SetTimeout(int time, Action function)
        {
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            tmr.Interval = time;
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate (object s, EventArgs ev)
            {
                function();
                tmr.Stop();
            });
            tmr.Start();

            timerMaxIndex++;
            var index = timerMaxIndex;
            timerList[timerMaxIndex] = tmr;            
            return index;
        }

        public void ClearInterval(int interval)
        {
            if (timerList[interval] == null)
                return;

            timerList[interval].Stop();
            timerList[interval] = null;
            if (interval == timerMaxIndex)
                timerMaxIndex--;
        }
    }
}
```

(Functions `a`, `b` and `c` were made just to test this.)

Comment: What's wrong (IMO) is to...do it. You do not need to (for example) use integer IDs when you have objects. Also you're using System.Windows.Forms.Timer, it's not accurate, it wastes more GDI resources and it won't _fire_ if UI is busy doing something else. Just use .NET timers as they are, you'll write less code and it'll be more robust (it doesn't mean you can't write few helper functions, just don't try to do things in JavaScript style using C#, it's...weird and I would say also _wrong_).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti about timers, which one should I use? System.Timers.Timer? or something else?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti and which way will be more C#-style? I want to wrap it into helper because I don't want to write repeatable code many times

Comment: There are three timers you may use in a WinForms application: System.Windows.Forms.Timer, System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer. To pick right one refer to MSDN (they have different use cases). Try to use Timer (also the one you're using now) without mimicking JavaScript (also try to drag & drop timer directly from WinForms designer) and you'll see you have less code than what you wrote...

Comment: Just as a side note, here's a blog implementing a similar idea: JavaScript-like timers. http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/easytimer__javascript_style_settimeout_and_setinterval_in_c.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

> Modularity, and hence separation of concerns, is achieved by
>   encapsulating information inside a section of code that has a
>   well-defined interface

That's why we should first think about the primary concerns of our application, and try to seperate these concerns into classes, which can then also be re-used if designed modularity in mind.

Therefore, Assuming what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

```
ExecutionPlan aInterval = ExecutionPlan.Repeat(500, a);
ExecutionPlan bInterval = ExecutionPlan.Repeat(500, b);
ExecutionPlan cInterval = ExecutionPlan.Repeat(500, c);

ExecutionPlan.Delay(3500, () => { aInterval.Abort(); });
ExecutionPlan.Delay(7000, () => { bInterval.Abort(); });
ExecutionPlan.Delay(10500, () => { cInterval.Abort(); });
```

You can wrap your timers in ExecutionPlan class.

Using a class for wrapping the timers have many benefits.

1. You keep track of class instances and not bare integer values,
2. You can re-use this class in other projects or forms (if designed & implemented correctly),
3. You can extend this class to enrich it's functions
4. etc.. (There are an infinite number of benefits)

Here is my ExecutionPlan class which works with an underlying `System.Timers.Timer`:

```
public class ExecutionPlan : IDisposable
{
    private System.Timers.Timer planTimer;
    private Action planAction;
    bool isRepeatedPlan;

    private ExecutionPlan(int millisecondsDelay, Action planAction, bool isRepeatedPlan)
    {
        planTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(millisecondsDelay);
        planTimer.Elapsed += GenericTimerCallback;
        planTimer.Enabled = true;

        this.planAction = planAction;
        this.isRepeatedPlan = isRepeatedPlan;
    }

    public static ExecutionPlan Delay(int millisecondsDelay, Action planAction)
    {
        return new ExecutionPlan(millisecondsDelay, planAction, false);
    }

    public static ExecutionPlan Repeat(int millisecondsInterval, Action planAction)
    {
        return new ExecutionPlan(millisecondsInterval, planAction, true);
    }

    private void GenericTimerCallback(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        planAction();
        if (!isRepeatedPlan)
        {
            Abort();
        }
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        planTimer.Enabled = false;
        planTimer.Elapsed -= GenericTimerCallback;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (planTimer != null)
        {
            Abort();
            planTimer.Dispose();
            planTimer = null;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(ExecutionPlan).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that in `GenericTimerCallback`, if a operation is called that does not resolve immediately, the `Delay` function will repeat itself. Moving the `Abort()` call above `planAction();` seems to correct that.

Comment: It **must be** noted, that there should be used `System.Timers.Timer` not the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Answer (score 4):

Right now your timer methods have dependencies on stuff that shouldn't be.

You're relying on `System.Windows.Form`. That's blocking you if you ever want to use these methods in a console application or well... stuff that isn't related to WinForms. Check for the [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class!

Your *helper* methods are relying on variables that aren't in their scope (The `Timer[]`). That's a dependency you want to remove.

To do so, we need a way to stop the timer. We could return the timer, but that might be a little too much for what we want to do. So let's create an interface, `IInterruptable`.

```
public interface IInterruptable
{
    void Stop();    
}
```

Now, we need something to wrap our `Timer` so we can implement the interface.

```
public class TimerInterrupter : IInterruptable
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public TimerInterrupter(Timer timer)
    {
        if (timer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(timer));
        _timer = timer;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

So far so good. That deals with the problem of the `Timer[]`.

Next, let's see how we can change your implementation using `System.Timers.Timer`.

Point one, not totally related to the new implementation but *very* related to your old one. Using `delegate` is a little old-school. Since C#... 3? There are Functions you can use, that are backward compatible to `delegate`. That means :

```
//Syntax might not be good, but you get the point
fooBar.SomeEvent += new delegate(object,object){asd();};
```

Becomes :

```
fooBar.SomeEvent += (a,b) => asd();
```

So, let's look at that timer! This `Timer` class as an `AutoReset` property, which well... auto-resets the timer at the end of each interval is set to `true`. Which will be the main difference between your `SetInterval` and `SetTimeout` methods.

```
public static IInterruptable SetInterval(int interval, Action function)
{
    Action functionCopy = (Action)function.Clone();
    Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = interval, AutoReset = true };
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => functionCopy();
    timer.Start();

    return new TimerInterrupter(timer);
}
```

Notice that the method is now `static`, since it's an helper method. You'll be able to use it in any context, which is great!

I changed the `time` parameter to `interval`, as it's clearer this way. You didn't pass a `time`, you passed a `time interval` as a parameter. It's important to be very clear.

I'm copying the `Action`. I'm not 100% sure that's useful, but it's to avoid a problem with references. If for example I did :

```
Action someFunction = CreateAFunctionThatIsntNull();
SetInterval(1,someFunction);
someFunction = null;
```

You're screwed. So copying the `Action` has a purpose here.

Now the `SetTimeout` :

```
public static IInterruptable SetTimeout(int interval, Action function)
{
    Action functionCopy = (Action)function.Clone();
    Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = interval, AutoReset = false };
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => functionCopy();
    timer.Start();

    return new TimerInterrupter(timer);
}
```

Notice something? Well, that's the same code, with *one* different variable in `AutoReset`. So let's take care of that by extracting another method :

```
public static class TimerHelper
{
    public static IInterruptable SetInterval(int interval, Action function)
    {
        return StartTimer(interval, function, true);
    }

    public static IInterruptable SetTimeout(int interval, Action function)
    {
        return StartTimer(interval, function, false);
    }

    private static IInterruptable StartTimer(int interval, Action function, bool autoReset)
    {
        Action functionCopy = (Action)function.Clone();
        Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = interval, AutoReset = autoReset };
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => functionCopy();
        timer.Start();

        return new TimerInterrupter(timer);
    }
}
```

That's the final version in my opinion. I think it looks better. Though there's a final problem. `SetTimeout` and `SetInterval` are terrible method names. I know the idea is to copy the Javascript functions, but let's make an exception. These methods names are not intuitive and overall pretty terrible. Maybe something like `ExecuteEvery` instead of `SetInterval` and `ExecuteIn` instead of `SetTimeout` would be better names.